# Encrypt/decrypt single octet with no padding using RSA_public_encrypt

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to encrypt the decimal number 1 with no padding using `RSA_public_encrypt`. Of course the result of this encryption should be 1 again. But in fact it is

Cipher:

```
5228673350895653896383201058815462877426144378065091716669226352446563314310753759122681282019606231774744798481087922688401463790373072832646006963123849664906627085625735903412727878929921552918090336305565457632762612646244666075746315455854479912774071351362988587769873374454538153517081634942043196173525640004822126101409481060928041484882764412543090155480476597339865942466034635200613687987398189458867055031285752787781897557950334515480742629110423562374837915117562936777536259795189526199285672603820591631423849227226304977053415509662563290672486408474162339095049681422645956742727171481170704
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am aware that there are high level routines in OpenSSL and also that using RSA without padding is insecure. This is just an experiment.

I am also aware that OpenSSL uses the Big Endian format. So I also tried to change the order of the input bytes to the encryption - then 1 was encrypted to 1. But implementing the decryption, taking into account the reverse byte order in both encryption and decryption, some numbers, like 2, were encrypted-decrypted correctly and others were not...very strange!

Here is my code for the encryption:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rsa.h"
#include "pem.h"

#define LENGTH 1000

int main(void)
{
    //Variables for message and cipher
    //BIGNUM format
    BIGNUM message_bignum, cipher_bignum;
    BIGNUM *ptr_message_bignum=&message_bignum;
    BIGNUM *ptr_cipher_bignum=&cipher_bignum;
    //Formatted as decimal string 
    unsigned char message_decimal[]="1";
    //binary format for input to RSA encryption
    unsigned char message[LENGTH]={0},cipher[LENGTH]={0};

    //Initialise RSA structure
    RSA *rsa=RSA_new();

    //Get public key
    BIO *publickey_handle=BIO_new_file("rsa_publickey.txt","rb");
    if(publickey_handle==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open key file!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(publickey_handle,&rsa,NULL,NULL);
    if(BIO_free(publickey_handle)==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error closing key file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Convert message to BIGNUM format
    BN_init(ptr_message_bignum);
    BN_dec2bn(&ptr_message_bignum,(const char *)message_decimal);
    //Convert message as BIGNUM to binary format
    BN_bn2bin(ptr_message_bignum,message);

    //Encrypt message in binary format
    if(RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_size(rsa),(const unsigned char*)message,cipher,rsa,RSA_NO_PADDING)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error during encryption!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Convert cipher to BIGNUM format
    BN_init(ptr_cipher_bignum);
    BN_bin2bn((const unsigned char*)cipher,RSA_size(rsa),ptr_cipher_bignum);
    //Convert cipher from BIGNUM format to decimal format and print it to stdout
    printf("Cipher:\n%s",BN_bn2dec(ptr_cipher_bignum));

    printf("\nDone!\n");

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is the result you get? How is it wrong? "Result isn't 1" doesn't really explain it.

Comment: I think there are easier ways to do what you are trying to do with the value 1. Why not simply declare it like `unsigned char message_decimal[] = 0x01;`? Or call `BN_set_word(bn, 0x01)`? Or use `BN_value_one`? See the [`bn_set_word`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_zero.html) man pages for the related functions. Or even `unsigned char message[RSA_size(rsa)]; memset(message,RSA_size(rsa),0x00); message[RSA_size(rsa)-1]=0x01;` (use C99 to compile it).

Comment: I want to understand how I can pass decimal numbers to RSA_public_encrypt(). Of course I could just pass an array, but that's not the point. I want to understand the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

As documented:

> `BN_bn2bin()` converts the absolute value of a into big-endian form and stores it at `to`. **`to` must point to `BN_num_bytes(a)` bytes of memory**.

But it doesn't. It first contains a single `00` because of `message[LENGTH]={0}`. Then it contains, well, whatever is in `LENGTH` amount of bytes.

In `RSA_public_encrypt` you use `RSA_size(rsa)` as first parameter, `flen`. `flen` however should be the result of `BN_num_bytes(&ptr_message_bignum)`, i.e. 1 byte. The output location `cipher` on the other hand must be able to store `RSA_size(rsa)` bytes.

Possibly the confusion comes from the fact that `BN_bn2bin` will store the value as the shortest Big Endian encoding (in bytes). For the value 1 that will of course be one byte, not `RSA_size(rsa)` bytes.

---

Edit: I found the [`RSA_padding_add_none`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_padding_add_none.html) method that could be able to resize.

Comment: In C, when you initialize an array with few initilalizers than the length of the array, then the rest of the array is set to 0. So it is wrong to say "well, whatever is in LENGTH" amount of bytes.

Comment: Ah, so it contained `010000.....`. Right. Still, `RSA_size` could overflow the array, if it wasn't for the overlarge array. But you are probably correct with that remark. I'll remove the comment, but beware of buffer fubars such as these. Heartbleed didn't fall out of the blue sky.

Comment: That's right. I should have calloced RSA_size(rsa) bytes for cipher. I will change this in the code. However, in this case, RSA_size(rsa) was 256 so it was fine.

Comment: According to the Openssl doc, the first argument of RSA_public_encrypt, flen, must satisfy:

flen must be less than RSA_size(rsa) - 11 for the PKCS #1 v1.5 based padding modes, less than RSA_size(rsa) - 41 for RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING and exactly RSA_size(rsa) for RSA_NO_PADDING.

So I can't just pass 1 for flen; encryption fails then.

Comment: But your answer was a very good hint; I think I know now why it failed: After conversion with BN_bn2bin(), I should have treated the message as a big endian integer, stored in RSA_size(rsa) bytes! For a one byte integer, I can just reverse the byte order, but actually I have to shift all the bytes to the right... So that's where the case-dependant behaviour comes from! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be able to replace `RSA_size(rsa)` in `RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_size(rsa)...`  with the value returned from `BN_num_bytes(&ptr_message_bignum)` (i.e. the value 1). No need for shifting anything. It's `int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding)` where `flen` is described as "encrypts the `flen` bytes"

Comment: You do all this trouble to convert your value 1 to a big number, then to binary. Funny enough the RSA encryption method will do exactly the opposite - convert to BN and then raise it with e modulo n  :)

Comment: Fixed answer, wasn't too clear on `flen` I must admit.

Comment: Did this fix it, maya?

Comment: No, there are two issues: First, BN_num_bytes must be called with ptr_message_bignum, not with the pointer's address. Second, if I call RSA_public_encrypt(BN_num_bytes(ptr_message_bignum),<...>) encryption fails. As I said in the fourth comment, the first argument of RSA_public_encrypt if called with RSA_NO_PADDING must be exactly RSA_size(rsa)... Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: It could well be the case that this is one of the more poorly documented OpenSSL features. In the end raw RSA (no padding) is just modular exponentiation. The plaintext needs to be converted to a number first. However, it could be that OpenSSL checks if the input is precisely the modulus size in bytes before performing the actual operation (to check that padding succeeded and that the encryption is safe). Otherwise the user may try and perform modular exponentiation of the value 1 :) In that case you need indeed to convert the big integer to a big endian representation. I'll check of the I2OSP

Comment: Hi Maarten, would you say it's clear now? I wrote some code to convert the result of BN2bin to big endian repsresentation with RSA_size(rsa) bytes. It seems the authors of RSA_encrypt didn't want users to do what I am doing :-)